# Selenium scraping one output but multiplied

Tags: python, selenium

So I am going to uni quite soon, and I am scraping a website for scholarships. I have used selenium and to scrape the titles, but it only outputs one title but multipled with the number of total titles on the page.

code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

#making the browser headless
firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")

#creating the driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options = firefox_options)

#URL
url = 'https://www.marj3.com/programs?fwp_degree_level=28aff2d9374a3b4ebf15be16e9cb664f&fwp_specializations_ar=0f1b95cc9471e2e421c4accc36c7c49e%2C7acecc33eb0c7e4e737e479d03235599%2Cb8508ad006f6f4177891a746b9a9b570%2C621a2eee69e1cb23624502173022d322%2Cb9df2d2680b2b186c20a13543269edd5%2Cfd611e512400e10e526896597317452b%2C7e9240f0dc4708eb7a78b5ddf6a99e8b%2C8c1886d7ed21025ad5bb40d4442290af&fwp_study_type_ar=full-time'

#Linking URl to driver
driver.get(url)

#container class: ecs-link-wrapper
#country_hosting: //*[@id="post-435735"]/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div
#title: //*[@id="post-435735"]/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/div/div/p/a
#money: //*[@id="post-435735"]/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/section[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/p
#type: #//*[@id="post-435735"]/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/section[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/p
#number of years: //*[@id="post-435735"]/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/ul/li/span[2]
#date of posting: //*[@id="post-435735"]/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li/span[2]

universities = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ecs-link-wrapper')
for uni in universities:
    university_title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.dce-elementor-post-435735 > div:nth-child(1) > section:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > section:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)').text
    hosting_country = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="post-435735"]/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div').text
    university_annual_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="post-435735"]/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/section[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/p').text
    uni_type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="post-435735"]/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/section[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/p').text
    number_of_years = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="post-435735"]/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/ul/li/span[2]').text
    date_of_posting = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="post-435735"]/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li/span[2]').text

    print(university_title)
```

my output

```
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
بكالوريوس الهندسة المعمارية والتصميم البيئي
```

url

> https://www.marj3.com/programs?fwp_degree_level=28aff2d9374a3b4ebf15be16e9cb664f&fwp_specializations_ar=0f1b95cc9471e2e421c4accc36c7c49e%2C7acecc33eb0c7e4e737e479d03235599%2Cb8508ad006f6f4177891a746b9a9b570%2C621a2eee69e1cb23624502173022d322%2Cb9df2d2680b2b186c20a13543269edd5%2Cfd611e512400e10e526896597317452b%2C7e9240f0dc4708eb7a78b5ddf6a99e8b%2C8c1886d7ed21025ad5bb40d4442290af&fwp_study_type_ar=full-time

Answer (score 0):

Check your for loop. You are running the same code as many times as HTTP elements with the `ecs-link-wrapper` class are in this webpage.

You probably want to use each of the elements found to get the different bits that you are interested.

I would also check your XPaths, I get the impression that you are using an the id of a particular post and that won't work in your loop.

Also, try to use most generic way to find your elements, if you rely on XPath, a tiny change in the webside code will break your scraper.